# Query to fetch parents on the basic of number of children

Tags: apex, soql, query

`Group__c` has a lookup relationship to `Account`. What should be the query to fetch the number of `Account` records which have more then N `Group__c` child records?

N can be anything like 3,5 etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `HAVING` clause and an aggregate query:

```
Integer matchingAccounts = [
    SELECT count(Id) records, Account__c FROM Group__c
    GROUP BY Account__c HAVING count(Id) > :numberOfChildren
].size();
```